# Is it possible to create a background service using PhoneGap to display notification in x intervals

Tags: cordova

I am working in an mobile native application which requires a background scanning of necessary data and display notification to the user after certain intervals.

But I am not sure how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a [background service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) as you normally would in Android. Then you need to create a [Plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) to call your service at your specified interval to query the data.